# Validate while user is typing and validate on submit

Tags: javascript, validation

I validate user input twice actually. While user is typing I check the input to provide some feedback to the user.

When the user submits the form I validate the input again to check whether the input is correct.

I think using both would cause redundancy and I would like to avoid that.

Is it correct to have just the first validation method?  What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you will definitely miss if you only validate while the user is typing is empty fields.

I think the best of both worlds is to add a "valid" class to valid inputs in your as-you-type validation. Then on submit, skip checking the inputs that have this class.

That said, client-side validation is mainly for the user experience. Server-side validation can always pick up on and notify the user of any errors the client-side validation missed. So it is up to you here to decide how much the client-side validation should do based on your form.

Comment: "skip checking the inputs that have this class" you don't mean skiping on the server side right?

Comment: @Mauricio, I actually meant skipping during the submit phase on the client side. Server side validation should never be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should Just validate on `onblur()` event for each field (Enough for client side).

And also validate on Server side , can't trust user input .